# VS Code runs python code in wrong terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

I want to run python code in VS Code with the button. But if I run the code it tries to run it on Ubuntu. If I run the code manually in my Powershell it works.
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hSfF.gif)

How can I fix it, so that VS Code runs the python code in the powershell?

Thnak you!

I already tried to select Powershell as default terminal, but it still changes to the ubutu terminal.

Comment: Hello! Have you can have a look at this page [https://www.w3schools.io/editor/vscode-change-default-terminal/?utm_content=cmp-true](https://www.w3schools.io/editor/vscode-change-default-terminal/?utm_content=cmp-true)

Comment: Thx, for the answer. But like I said, changing the default terminal does not fix my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the fold in the bottom right corner， then choose **Select Default Profile**.

[image]

[image]

Then close the terminal, restart vscode, and rerun the Python file.

Comment: Thx, for the answer. But like I said, changing the default terminal does not fix my issue. –

Comment: Have you tried to update vscode or reinstall vscode.